# two big table join slow

Tags: sql, hive

this is a simple select query:

```
SELECT *
  from (select * from ods_rfx_prod where dt = '2017-06-07') p
  left join (select * from ods_rfx_prod_ext where dt = '2017-06-07') pt
    on p.prod_id = pt.prod_id
```

two table (ods_rfx_prod,ods_rfx_prod_ext) all partitioned by 'dt' and stored as RCFile.

table p contains 3000w columns,table pt contains 3500w columns.
`p.prod_id`  and `pt.prod_id` has no null and blanks record.

it runs nearly for 40min~50min.
i don't know how to optimize it.

Comment: Are the dt columns indexed?

Comment: you can try an in your sql console :
EXPLAIN SELECT *
  from (select * from ods_rfx_prod where dt = '2017-06-07') p
  left join (select * from ods_rfx_prod_ext where dt = '2017-06-07') pt
    on p.prod_id = pt.prod_id    

for documentation, https://www.sitepoint.com/explain-sql-explain-queries/

Comment: Tables volumes/number of records? tables DDL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try many different combinations to check if the performance increases.

1) As you have a where condition , check if the column is indexed

2) Since it is a date column you can create partitions on it

3) As you are joining on productID you can try to sort the data on productID and then apply the join

4) You can also try to create buckets by hashing the productID, so that the query can take advantage of map side join

Comment: two tables have been partitioned by dt.